# Customize LDAP failed login attempts counter

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, password-policy, apache-directory

I know that you can use LDAP to count the number of failed bindings attempt to lockout an account when a limit is reached(pwdMaxFailure, pwdLockout, pwdLockoutDuration attributes). 
Is there any way I could customize LDAP so that consecutive login attempts using the same username and password should only count at a single failed login, meaning that the failed login counter should only be incremented by one?
I'm using Apache Directory in a Java project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An interesting concept. Many failed logins using the same credentials is usually not a security event. Be aware that you will have to find some way to store the last-tried password. This would require a significant customization.

For ApacheDS, you can try to use an `Interceptor`, I have done some customizations using that interface. An `Interceptor` allows you to be notified when certain events take place in ApacheDS and react on them.

Your interceptor should handle `bind()` events. See https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/gen-docs/2.0.0.AM25/apidocs/org/apache/directory/server/core/api/interceptor/Interceptor.html for the specification.